# form validation in phonegap & jQueryMobile didnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to make a form validation in my phonegap , jQuery mobile App. But when i press on submit button even if there  is empty fields  the validation didn't work , why is that ?
 what is the error in my code? and how i can validate radio buttons

i have searched over the internet  about validation and i have used the same way but the problem didn't solved

please help me ...

Thanks in advance.

this my code :

**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>


     <html>

     <head>

     <meta charset="utf-8" />

     <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />

     <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,                   minimum-scale=1, width=device-width,
      height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/color.css">
      <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>      
      <link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css"     rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body>


    <div data-role="page"    id="NewReminder"   >

        <div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed"    data-theme="b" >
            <img  src="www\css\images\title_bar.png "   />
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

         <form   id="RminderInfo_Form" >

         <ul   data-role="listview"   data-inset="true"     id="RminderInfo_FormList" >

           <li>
           <div   data-role="fieldcontain" >
           <input type="text"   name="MedName"  id="MedName"    size="35"   />
           <label for="MedName"     id="MedName_Label" > medicine name</label>
            </div>
            </li>


            <li>

            <div      class="ui-grid-a">

            <div     class="ui-block-a">
            <input type="radio"    id="after"   name="after"  />
            <label  for="after"    > after meal </label>
            </div>

            <div    class="ui-block-b">
           <input type="radio"     name="before  "  id="before"  value="before meal" />
           <label  for="before"    > before meal</label>
           </div >
           </li>

           <li>

           <div   data-role="fieldcontain" >

           <input type="number"   name="Dailytake_Times"  id="Dailytake_Times"     style="width:3px;"   />
           <label for="Dailytake_Times"     data-inline="true"      id="Dailytake_TimesLabel"> number of doases</label>

            </div>
            </li>

           <li    id="doases"   style="display:none;"  >

           </li>

           <li>
          <fieldset>
          <legend ><h2 >  medicine type  </h2></legend>

         <input type="radio"    id="Capsule"   name="Capsule"  />
        <label  for="Capsule"    >Capsule</label>

       <input type="radio"     name="Spray  "  id="Spray"  />
       <label  for="Spray"    > spray</label>

       <input type="radio"     name="Diameter  "  id="Diameter"  />
       <label  for="Diameter"    > diameter</label>

       <input type="radio"     name="salve "  id="salve"  />
       <label  for="salve"    > salve</label>

       </fieldset>
       </li>
       <li     style="display:none;" >
       <div  id="Medicine_quant"  >

       <div   data-role="fieldcontain" >

       <input type="number"   name="MedQuantity"  id="MedQuantity"  />
       <label for="MedQuantity"   id="MedQuantity_Label"   > medicine quantity</label>

      </div>
      </div>

       </li>
       <li>
       <div   data-role="fieldcontain" >

        <input type="date"   name="Med_ExpireDate"  id="Med_ExpireDate"  />
        <label for="Med_ExpireDate"    data-inline="true"   id="Med_ExpireDateLabel">   medicine expire date </label>

        </div>
        </li>
        <li> 

        <input type="submit"      data-theme="a"     data-inline="true"  value=" save  "/>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        </body>

        </html>
```

**index.js**

```
      document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

     function   onDeviceReady () {

     VMedName = $('#MedName');
     VMedQuantity = $('#MedQuantity');
     VDailytake_Times = $('#Dailytake_Times');
     VMedQuantity = $('#MedQuantity');
     VMed_ExpireDate = $('#Med_ExpireDate');

     MedNameLabel = $('#MedName_Label');
     DailytakeTimesLabel = $('#Dailytake_TimesLabel');
     MedQuantityLabel = $('#MedQuantity_Label');
     MedExpireDateLabel = $('#Med_ExpireDateLabel');

    var MISSING = "missing";


    $('#RminderInfo_Form') .submit(function(){

      var err = false;

  // Reset the previously highlighted form elements//

    MedNameLabel.removeClass(MISSING); 
    DailytakeTimesLabel.removeClass(MISSING);
    MedQuantityLabel .removeClass(MISSING);
    MedExpireDateLabel.removeClass(MISSING);        

  // Perform form validation//


  if(VMedName.val()==null||VMedName.val()== " "){   
      MedNameLabel.addClass(MISSING);   
      err = true;
     }

   if(VMedQuantity.val()==null||VMedQuantity.val()== " "){   
      MedQuantityLabel.addClass(MISSING);   
      err = true;
    }

  if(VDailytake_Times.val()==null||VDailytake_Times.val()== " "){   
      DailytakeTimesLabel.addClass(MISSING);   
      err = true;
    }

  if(VMed_ExpireDate.val()==null||VMed_ExpireDate.val()== " "){   
      MedExpireDateLabel.addClass(MISSING);   
      err = true;
    }



    });



      }
```

Comment: try with updated code also you need to use normal button at the place of submit and form will submit when your validation will complete then in else condition you add submit form with the help of trigger function... gud luck

Answer (score 0):

```
Use your code in this format:     

     var VMedName = $('#MedName').val();
     var VMedQuantity = $('#MedQuantity').val();
     var VDailytake_Times = $('#Dailytake_Times').val();
     var VMedQuantity = $('#MedQuantity').val();
     var VMed_ExpireDate = $('#Med_ExpireDate').val();

     var MedNameLabel = $('#MedName_Label').val();
     var DailytakeTimesLabel = $('#Dailytake_TimesLabel').val();
     var MedQuantityLabel = $('#MedQuantity_Label').val();
     var MedExpireDateLabel = $('#Med_ExpireDateLabel').val();



   and use like this:



  if((VMedName ==null) || (VMedName == " ") || (VMedName == undefined) ){
        // your code
}
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help me , i tried it but the problem still .. the validation doesn't work

Comment: what error appears, use alerts for finding error, i think problem with submitting form use trigger function for form submit..

Comment: also use always short method like you wrote in a lengthy way and problem can be here also use this: $(".MISSING").removeClass("MISSING");

Comment: i have used if not if else because i want to check all text fields .i used alerts and it doesn't enter the if statement

Comment: even if the input field is empty

Comment: you can validate radio buttons by checked attribute property and for this can you provide me jsfiddle example for more clear and first you use trigger function for submit your form

Comment: no problem i will solve your issue you just send me your jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0):

When the input is empty, the value is not null but is an empty string.
You can test it's value in the console if you are using chrome developer tools, firebug, etc.